# Django + Tempus Dominus - Submit django form without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have a functioning datepicker on my django app called [tempus dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Events/). I am having some trouble trying to set this datepicker to submit without having to click on a submit button.

Their documentation is horrible but I finally figured at least part of it, it seems that I have to trigger one of their custom events (change.datetimepicker). Below you will find my implementation... My js skills are quite rusty so probably the problem lies somewhere there...

my **forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

date_from = forms.DateField(
    required=True,
    widget=DatePicker(
        options={
            'minDate': '2018-01-20',
            'maxDate': '2020-10-20',
        },
    ),
    initial='2020-08-01',

)

date_to = forms.DateField(
    required=True,
    widget=DatePicker(
        options={
            'minDate': '2018-01-20',
            'maxDate': '2020-10-20',
        },
    ),
    initial='2020-10-19',

)
```

my **template**

```
<div class="col" id="form_div">
      <form method="post" action="." id="datetimepicker" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="enviar"  style="width:70px" />
      </form>

    </div>
```

my **js file**

```
    $("#datetimepicker").on("change.datetimepicker", function () {

    $( "#datetimepicker" ).submit();
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered trying `django-tempus-dominus`? https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-tempus-dominus The underlying package is come back from maintenance mode and this package will as well.

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what I ended up doing after all. Forgot to updated this thread though... Thanks for the input anyway!